# Как унаследовать класс А от двух абстрактных классов B и C?

Tags: java, наследование

Класс А должен быть унаследован от двух абстрактных классов B и C. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. а то очень похоже на XY-проблему.

Comment: унаследовать сначала от B, потом от С

Answer (score 7):

В Java нет множественного наследования, поэтому никаким образом не получится унаследовать класс от двух и более других классов.

Посмотрите в сторону интерфейсов, может быть, Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью них. Например, унаследовать класс от какого-то одного класса и реализовать в дочернем классе один или несколько интерфейсов.